# Disadvantages of using a short string for an enum rather than an int?

Tags: database-design, schema

I've got many enum-like fields in my database. Just an integer that's a FK to another table that might contain a display name or maybe a little additional data. Problem is, the number is pretty meaningless and not very nice to work with in the code. Also, you might run into some name/key clashing if you try to merge some of these enums from different databases, or move the data around, or if it's an autoincrement...

Are there any downsides of just using a short string? Kind of like a constant? And use that as the primary key instead? An int is usually 4 bytes, I'm thinking I don't really need more than 10 chars, so a varchar(10) would do... I don't suspect disk usage would really be an issue.

Comment: It sounds like you and I are on the same wavelength here. I've never seen any evidence that has made me not want to use natural keys (provided they are reasonable/indexable).

Comment: P.S. Sorry for kind of hijacking your question. :P

Comment: @Kevin: Haha, no problem. The more questions you ask, the more I learn too :)

Answer (score 3):

My personal approach is to use text keys for items that would require changing code to add or remove. If a given item is something that a user should be able to add or remove, then I would stick with a surrogate key. This allows for your code to use text values which is far easier to read. An example might be "states" (e.g. On/Off, Acquired/Pending/Sold). Invariably there will be code that acts differently depending on the state and thus, that code needs look for specific state values. Those "states" are not something that anyone can simply add or remove or even rename. Code is dependent on them. Thus, for these, I use a string PK. However, something like say "categories" a user should be able to add or remove those at will and in those cases a surrogate key (combined with the appropriate business key) is better.

Comment: Can you define "business key" in this case? Also, wouldn't it be more "natural" to have a categories table and a userCategories table joining the user and category as a natural PK?

Comment: @Kevin Peno - RE: Business Key. A surrogate key is, by definition, arbitrary. Identity/AutoNumber columns have no inherit meaning. There must be some other constraint on the table that enforces uniqueness. If you have a table of categories for example, with a name column and an AutoNumber column, there is nothing to stop someone from adding duplicate categories differentiated only by an arbitrary value. A business key is what a user would use to differentiate one row from another.

Comment: @Thomas, I got ya. I just wanted to be sure we were on the same page. Given your answer, wouldn't the answer to my second question be "yes" (in most cases)?

Comment: @Kevin Peno - RE: Categories - The exact schema of the categories isn't as important as the idea that you would want to allow a user to create categories at will as opposed to values on which code is reliant. You would never want to hard code the use of a specific category because you have to assume those could change. However, something like states in a pipeline process might have very specific behaviors such that you would not want to allow users to create them ad hoc.

Comment: @Kevin Peno - Correct. A varchar(10) vs an int is negligible IMO. What matters most is clarity of the code and consistency of the data.

Comment: Right, but it's not hard to have code understand a dynamic category (in this case). Nor is it hard for it to understand it's a `userCategory`. So why would you only use text keys for "hardcoded" values/constants?

Comment: Yes...this is exactly the use-case I had in mind. Thanks :) Feel a little better about using a string PK now.

Comment: @Kevin Peno - I would never want to write hard code a request for a specific user enterable value if I could help it. The reason is that the user could change or remove the value and break the query. Whereas with a system reliant value, there is a speed bump that helps prevent people from willy-nilly adding a value.

Comment: @Thomas, you seem to be going opposite of my question. I'm, basically, asking, "why you would not always use the text-based string since logically any system can handle dealing with dynamic values?" I've never suggested hardcoding custom attributes.

Comment: @Kevin Peno - What it sounds like you are asking is, "why use surrogate keys?" There are plenty of reasons: immutability, narrow in size, easier to reference for tables with multi-column keys. If you are asking "why use integer surrogate keys specifically over system generated text keys?", the answer would be simplicity and the advantage that many vendors provide a feature to do just that.

Comment: @Thomas, I'm not really. I was just trying to fully understand your answer because I was curious like the OP :) Thanks for dealing with the Q's

Comment: @Kevin Peno - No problem. It helps to ask questions to help my clarity and help others.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how immutable the key is.

If we're talking about linking to a table of US states using a postal code as a key, for example, there is no harm.  It is exceedingly unlikely that anyone would ever change California's postal code from CA to something else, for example, so storing that as a key would be perfectly reasonable.

On the other hand, something like an Order Status Code is likely to change over time.  When you first build the application, you may have a handful of statuses (i.e. "Taken", "Shipped", "Complete").  But then over time, the business may decide that new statuses need to be added and existing statuses need to be modified-- they may want to take the "Shipped" status, for example, and decompose that into "OnPallet", "InTransit", and "InCustoms".  If that happens and you're relying on "Shipped" being a key, you'll have a bunch of updates to do to all the rows in the `Order` table that have a "Shipped" key or you would end up with a bunch of orders that have a less meaningful key.  If you use a meaningless numeric key, on the other hand, you would merely have to update the `Order_Status` table to insert the new values and to update the one "Shipped" row.

Comment: In your example, wouldn't you have a mess anyway? Splitting a key in 3 would cause it's own problems. Assuming it's just a renaming issue, isn't that what `FK`s are for? And, if a key is retired (e.g., `Shipped` retired for `OnPallet`, `InTransit`, & `InCustoms`) doesn't that imply that you actually need an active/inactive field?

Comment: As I said to Thomas, I'm just trying to understand your answer because I'm as curious as the OP on this subject.

Comment: @Kevin - The foreign key would ensure that if you had a value "Shipped" in the `Order` table that there was a related row in the `Order_Status` table.  And when the key gets split, someone would need to decide how to handle existing orders (i.e. existing "Shipped" orders should go to "InTransit").  If you've got meaningless keys, that's 1 update and 2 inserts into `Order_Status`.  If you have meaningful keys, however, you end up either with a ton of `Order` rows with a "Shipped" status that users now have to know maps to "InTransit" or you end up updating tons of rows in `Order`.

Comment: @Kevin (continued) - I've seen cases where people using meaningful keys like this ended up with entire business units using the nomenclature of statuses from 3 systems ago because they relied on the status rather than looking at the new name in the `Order_Status` table which caused no end of grief when the mappings were less than obvious.  And it caused plenty of duplicate/ wasted effort as different projects ended up with slightly different mappings.

Comment: @Justin: I guess I just don't fully understand how/why updating is bad? I thought the whole reason to have stuff in a db was because it is mutable. Otherwise, why wouldn't I just hardcode statuses in my code too? Why bother with the `Order_Status` table?

Comment: @Kevin - Updating is fine.  It's the difference between updating 2 rows in the lookup table vs. updating millions of rows in the `Order` table which may create various locking issues depending on the database implementation.

Comment: Again though, why even bother with the `Order_Status` table and opt for an `enum` in the language of choice (which could still act as surrogate). I've got to update the code either way. (Sorry, playing devil's advocate now.)

Comment: Eh? If you just want change the display name of "Shipped" to "In Transit" and then add a couple more entries, you can still do that... the string key is mostly just for readability. I understand what you mean though, when suddenly you give it a different meaning, but.. the same applies to integers too. "4" might represent one status, and then a new one... people will be scratching there heads wondering what the heck it is/does either way. I don't see why updating a million records to rename your constant is an issue though.. you only have to run the query once.

Comment: Actually... in our case, we have about 50 databases, so it's a little more of a hassle, but... refactoring due to requirements changing is always a b*tch :p

Comment: @Mark, that's my stance on it. I like my data mutable and I see no issue updating records (even a few million). I was trying to understand the other side of it (@Justin's side). Thanks for weighing in.